# Problem with Eclipse connection to SQL Server 2022 by SSL

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2022

I have a website project in Eclipse and connect to database in SQL Server 2022. When I console my project, Eclipse has warned me: WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : "encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ClientConnectionId:5247f69c-9b19-4fdd-82c7-52026f92374d.

I have searched the fault on Google, Youtube and Stackoverflow too but it seems like no one has met this error before. I have using jdk-20 and I use JDBC for connecting to SQL Server. Please help me. Thank you so much.